# Как открыть файл Rust .rs

Tags: rust

Я хочу начать кодить на Rust, но я категорически не понимаю где нужно начать писать код, я скачал Rust установил его и даже создал файл, но не понимаю как его открыть и начать кодить.

Comment: Открыть файл и начать писать код можно в любом текстовом редакторе, хоть в блокноте. Используйте, например, sublime text 3 или любой другой редактор кода.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала в консоли пишем
cargo init <название-проекта>
Появится папка с названием, которое мы указали выше.
В ней будет папка src, в этой папке будет файл .rc, в него и надо писать код.
Сам файл можно открыть текстовым редактором, например, VS Code, Sublime Text и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Выполните в терминале

```
cargo new hello
```

Откройте файл `hello/src/main.rs` в любом текстовом редакторе и измените, как вам нужно. Для компиляции и запуска программы выполните внутри директории `hello` команду:

```
cargo run
```